# Closed subespace of Kernel of linear continuous map in Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $T:X\to Y$ be a continuous linear  map between two Banach spaces. Assume that there is some closed subspace $A$ of $X$ such that $X/A$ is isometrically isomorphic to $Y$. If $A\subseteq \text{Ker }T$, is it possible to prove that $A=\text{Ker }T$?

Comment: In what sense isomorphic?

Comment: As Banach spaces.

Comment: Isometric linear isomorphism thus?

Comment: Yes., I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=Y=\ell^{2}$ with the usual basis $(e_n)$ and let $A$ be the closed subspace spanned by $\{e_2,e_4,...\}$. Let $T$ be the projection on the closed subspace spanned by $\{e_3,e_5,e_7...\}$. [Explicitly $T(\sum a_ne_n)=a_3e_3+a_5e_5+a_7e_7+\cdots $].  This is a clear counter-example since $e_1$ is in the kernel of $T$ but not in $A$.

[$\sum a_n e_n \to \sum a_n e_{2n}$ is an isometric isomorphism from $A$ onto $Y$].

Answer (score 0):

No, this is false. Let $X=\ell^2$, the separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, and $T:X\to X$ be the "left shift by two" operator, $L^2$, where $L$ is the right shift. Let $A$ be the span of the first standard basis vector $e_1$. Then $A\subseteq \text{Ker } T$, and $X/A$ is a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space, and therefore isometrically isomorphic to $X$. But the kernel of $T$ is two-dimensional. We can also construct examples where $T$ is not onto, just by post-composing with the right shift operator.